# Python Discord OAuth2 - Bad Request (Guild.Join)

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, discord

Hi i'm trying to add a user to my guild using Discord's API.

The Scope I'm using is Guild.Join, Identify and Guilds. `identify%20guilds%20guilds.join`

The URL Is `https://discordapp.com/api`.

Here's my code:

```
@staticmethod
    def add_to_guild(access_token, userID):
        url = f"https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/{guildId that I cant show}/members/{userID}"

        botToken = "<Bot Token I can't SHow haha>"

        headers = {
            "Authorization" : f"Bot {botToken}",
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        payload = {
            'access_token' : access_token
        }

        response = requests.put(url=url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        print(response.text)
```

when I call this method, I receive this error:

`{"message": "400: Bad Request", "code": 0}`

I've been through the Discord's Documentation countless of times and searched the internet to no avail.

Can someone please help ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking through the docs (tbh, I haven't done this in a while and I forgot a lot), but did you double-check to see that the bot has the proper permissions to add people?

Comment: @downwithocp Yes it has.

Comment: My next idea is to check that the user id variable is properly named/called. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User

Answer (score 0):

you had to replace `data` to `json`

```py
    def add_to_guild(access_token, userID):
        print(userID)
        url = f"{Oauth.discord_api_url}/guilds/<GuildID>/members/{userID}"

        headers = {
            "Authorization" : "Bot <bottoken>",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }

        payload = {
            'access_token' : str(access_token)
        }

        response = requests.put(url=url, json=payload, headers=headers)
        print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The userID is enough I am not sure why you want the payload or access token; Try to drop the payload part.
2. If you are trying to add a user, the user has to agree to grant you some permissions check here https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes so the token I think will be the "Bearer" tokens. Check the doc I've shared.